# What does it mean, "location disabled" in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, geolocation

I'd like to know what it means when in Settings of Ubuntu 20.04 I set the switch to "Location services tuned off".

I am a newbie to Ubuntu.

- I have set the toggle to location services turned off
- In the taskbar menu (that I have at the bottom) there is clearly indicated "location disabled":
  [image: PIC]

BUT:

- in the taskbar I have the location icon appearing and
- when I click on 'my location' in  GNOME Maps, the device is precisely showing my current location.

How can I be sure that my location is not communicated to the outside?